# How to remove the quantization noise from a given quantized signal?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Say, I have an analog signal and it's discrete representation:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as py

def sin(frequency = 1, time = 1, sampling = 128, phi = 0):
    '''
    Sinus function for a given frequency in Hz, length in time,
    sampling frequency, and phase.
    '''
    dt = 1.0 / sampling
    t = np.arange(0, time, dt)
    s = np.sin((2 * np.pi * frequency * t) + phi)
    return s, t

s_analog_1, t_analog_1 = sin(frequency = 1, sampling = 1000)
py.plot(t_analog_1, s_analog_1, linewidth = '1.5', color = 'red', 
label = 'analog signal')

s_analog_2, t_analog_2 = sin(frequency = 1, sampling = 10)
py.plot(t_analog_2, s_analog_2, 'o', color = 'red')

# Calculate the quantization noise, ie "R/2^N"
s_discrete, t_discrete = sin(frequency = 1, sampling = 10)
N = 3
R = 2
dy = R/2**N
s_quantized = np.floor(s_discrete / dy) * dy + 0.5 *dy

py.plot(t_discrete, s_quantized, color = 'gray', label = 'discrete signal')
py.plot(t_discrete, s_quantized, 'o', color = 'gray')

py.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='10')

py.show()
```

Analog to Digital Converter is 3 bit level and it's measure range is 2. How can I remove the quntized noise from the discrete signal representation so it will fit the analog signal representation? The question is asked in the context of situation, when I have already gathered discrete signal. In the removal process I can use the quantization noise coefficient, i.e `dy = R/2^N`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are looking to fit a sine wave to your data, why not just fit a sine wave to your data?  You need to decide whether frequency and phase are fixed or free parameters to be fit.

Comment: Generally speaking, low-path filtering will usually be the most feasible approach. If you already have gathered data, looking at the the power spectral density (with http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=psd#matplotlib.pyplot.psd) will help find adequate parameters. `scipy.filter` has methods for designing filters (http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/FIRFilter). Alternatively, you can use `rfft()`/`irfft()` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fftpack.html#one-dimensional-discrete-fourier-transforms) for setting the appropriate frequency regions to zero.

Comment: @frank128791 First I want to adjust the position of the gray dots to the position of the red dots.

Comment: @bluevoxel  How do you know the positions of the red dots?  Do you already know the phase, frequency and/or amplitude of the sine wave?  Obviously, if you already knew where the grey dots were supposed to go, you would just assign the "correct" values based on the time the data were acquired.